# Spawning enemies in four different positions with a fixed trajectory in android game

Tags: java, android, android-studio, andengine

This is my first android game, I appreciate all the help. I want to define 4 spawning zones starting from out of the screen (left, right, up and down). Enemies coming from this areas have a fixed trajectory to the center, when this enemies come into the screen the player can move them to a specific corner, but if it lets go of it a new trajectory has to be calculated so it keeps moving to the center.

I am having trouble thinking on how to define this 4 areas, there is also 4 types enemies (they are the same, but they have a different color), should I place this 4 enemies on an arrayList ?. If I know how to define this 4 spawning areas which randomly decides where to spawn I then don't exactly know how to define the fixed trajectory to the center. Also, need to lower the speed to a more adecuate one. (Sorry if this seems like a lot am asking)

Current code looks like this (I am using AndEngine library):

```
public class gameEscene extends baseScene {

    // Regions for images
    private ITextureRegion BackgroundRegion;
    private ITextureRegion Corner;
    private ITextureRegion Center;
    private ITextureRegion Marco;
    // Sprites
    private Sprite spriteBackground;
    private Sprite spriteCorner;
    private Sprite spriteCenter;
    private Sprite spriteMarco;


    //  Enemies
    private ArrayList<Enemies> listEnemies;
    private ITextureRegion regionEnemy;
    //  Time to generate enemies
    private float timeEnemies = 0;              //  Counter
    private float   TIME_LIMIT  =   2.5f;       //  Every 2.5s it creates


    @Override
    public void loadResources() {
        BackgroundRegion = loadImage("black.jpg");
       Corner = loadImage("Corner_T.png");
        Center = loadImage("Center.png");
        Marco = loadImage("m.png");
        regionEnemy = loadimage("ship.png");
    }

    private void createEnemies() {
        for (int x = 700; x <= 1200; x += 100) {
            for (int y = 100; y <= 700; y += 100) {
                Sprite ship = loadSprite(x, y, regionEnemy);
                attachChild(ship);
                Enemies enemy = new Enemies(ship);
                listEnemies.add(enemy);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void createScene() {
        listEnemies = new ArrayList<>();
        spriteBackground = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, BackgroundRegion);
        spriteCorner = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Corner);
        spriteCenter = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Center);
        spriteMarco = loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH/2, GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT/2, Marco);
        attachChild(spriteBackground);
        attachChild(spriteCorner);
        attachChild(spriteCenter);
        attachChild(spriteMarco);
        createEnemies();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackKeyPressed() {
        // Regresar al menú principal
        admScenes.createMenuScenes();
        admScenes.setScene(SceneType.MENU_SCENE);
        admScene.liberateGameScene();
    }

    @Override
    public sceneType getSceneType() {
        return sceneType.GAME_SCENE;
    }

    @Override
    public void liberateScene() {
        this.detachSelf();
        this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void liberateResources() {
       BackgroundRegion.getTexture().unload();
        Corner.getTexture().unload();
        Center.getTexture().unload();
        Marco.getTexture().unload();
        regionEnemy.getTexture().unload();
        BackgroundRegion = null;
        Corner = null;
        Center = null;
        Marco = null;
        regionEnemy = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)   {

        super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        timeEnemies +=  pSecondsElapsed;        //  Acumulates time
        if  (timeEnemies>TIME_LIMIT)    {   //  Time has completed
            tiemeEnemies    =   0;
            Sprite spriteEnemy  =   loadSprite(GameControl.CAMARA_WIDTH+regionEnemy.getWidth(),
                    (float)(Math.random()*GameControl.CAMARA_HEIGHT-regionEnemy.getHeight())    +
                            regionEnemy.getHeight(),regionEnemy);

            Enemies newEnemy = new Enemies(spriteEnemies);
            //newEnemies.mover(0,10);
            listEnemies.add(newEnemy);  //  Adds it to the scene
            attachChild(newEnemy.getSpriteEnemy()); //  Adds it to the list
        }

        //  Updates every enemy and sees if any has gotten out of the screen
        for (int    i=listEnemies.size()-1; i>=0;   i--)    {
            Enemies enemy   =   listEnemies.get(i);
            enemy.mover(-10, 0);
            if  (enemy.getSpriteEnemy().getX()<-enemy.getSpriteEnemy().getWidth())  {
                detachChild(enemy.getSpriteEnemy());        //  Deletes it from the scene
                listEnemies.remove(enemy);                                                                  //  eliminates it from the list
            }
            //  Checks the collision of enemy with another sprite

            if  (spriteCenter.collidesWith(enemy.getSpriteEnemy())) {
                detachChild(enemy.getSpriteEnemy());
                //enemies.remove(enemy);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

`Enemies` class looks like this:

```
public class Enemies {

    private Sprite sprite;

    public Enemies(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public Sprite getSpriteEnemy() {
        return sprite;
    }

    public void setSprite(Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public void mover(int dx, int dy) {
        sprite.setPosition( sprite.getX()+dx, sprite.getY()+dy );
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes an ArrayList will work well. For your question about trajectories, you need some trigonometry.

```
double angle = Math.atan2(sprite.getY()-centerY,sprite.getX()-centerX);
```

This uses inverse tangent to give you the trajectory angle. You may need to adjust this number a bit to get the correct rotation angle for your sprite.

For instance, if your sprite is in the vertical center but on the right edge this function will return 0. However if your sprite faces forward by default you will need to rotate it 90 degrees counterclockwise at this position. I don't know exactly how rotation works in your library, but an appropriate code may be `sprite.setRotation(angle-Math.PI/2)` (PI radians = 180 degrees).

Comment: Going to try this. Do you know how I can set 4 different spawning areas for enemies coming out of the screen (left, right, up and down) ? This areas will be selected at random.

Comment: What I would do is generate 2 random numbers from 0 to height and 2 random numbers from 0 to width, and set the spawn locations as (0,r1) , (width,r2) , (r3,0) , (r4,height).

Comment: Would this coordinates be sent into a method like setPosition ?

Comment: Yes, indeed they would.

Comment: Tried it and unfortunately it seems this methods sets the sprite in that position and can't be moved afterwards.

Comment: That seems weird. Just call setPosition every time you want to move it.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayList will work well work well for this.

In regards to using trajectories, I noticed another comment recommended using trigonometry. Obviously you would need this assuming you want to set a rotation for the image, although I didn't notice anything in your post saying you wanted the enemy to face the centre. If you don't need it, then using trig is usually a poor choice - although this will probably get the job done to the extent you need it for what I am assuming is a very simple app, it generally isn't a very good idea since trig calculations are quite expensive, and what you will obtain will almost always be inaccurate anyway.

For moving towards the centre without rotating the image, I would recommend simply determining the gradient you need to move, and then adjusting this velocity vector using a scalar so it is at the correct speed (think Pythagoras). If you wanted to be having a constant speed, you would probably also need the square root function, which is also a little expensive, but should definitely be much cheaper than using the trig method.

Comment: I think you should explain how to do the mathematical procedures you are describing, because not everyone knows them.

Comment: For determining the gradient, you simply calculate rise/run = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2) where (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are respectively the coordinates of the enemy and the centre.

Comment: Say then you wanted a distance of k per frame, then what our gradient tells us is the (ratio of y movement)/(ratio of x movement). We want to adjust the movement in x and y so that so that the total movement is k. This is done by calculating a constant c where c = k/(sqrt((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)), then the correct movement in x and y is c*(x2-x1) and c*(y2-y1) respectively. You simply add these to your x and y values and you have moved as you desired - towards the centre and the correct length.

Comment: Note btw that you don't actually have to calculate gradient in this. It's just helpful in understanding.

Comment: yes, i understand that in this example all you really need to do is take the slope, but gradient is the bigger conceptual concept.